# Rails 3.2.11 & Grape cannot such file: app/api/v1.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, grape-api

I trying to run Grape API in Rails 3.2.11 app. According to grape documentation I should add following lines to my config/application.rb.

```
# Auto-load API and its subdirectories
config.paths.add "app/api", :glob => "**/*.rb"
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/api/*"]
```

And create config/initializers/reload_api.rb with below code:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  api_files = Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/api/**/*.rb"]
  api_reloader = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker.new(api_files) do
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
  end
  ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
    api_reloader.execute_if_updated
  end
end
```

But it's not working for me. Here is my code. In my app/api/v1.rb:

```
module Api
  class V1 < Grape::API

    get '/hello' do
      []
    end
  end
end
```

And my config/routes.rb:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  mount Api::V1 => "/"
end
```

When I run `rake routes` I get following errors:

```
uninitialized constant Api
/home/zoloo/code/nomin/config/routes.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
/home/zoloo/code/nomin/config/routes.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/zoloo/code/nomin/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/zoloo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.11/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It's clear exception said Rails cannot load my api. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the autoload paths to:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app"]
```

When require tries to resolve `Api::V1` it will first look for a file called `api_v1.rb`. That doesn't exist. Then it's going to look for `api/v1.rb` in all autoload paths. And you don't have `app` in the autoload paths, but you do have `app/api` with all its subfolders. With the above code you would have to put `v1.rb` into `app/api/api/v1.rb`.